# How to find what message I just deserialized with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I've been happily using protobuf+ZeroMQ between some of my C++ applications for awhile now. I need to write a C# application. I've got Protobuf-NET working and I believe I've finally worked out how to deserialize from a ZeroMQ message, but I can't for the life of me work out how to see what message is in the deserialized data.
In my C++ applications I would deserialize to a class and I was able to simply do a:

```
if(msg.has_msgTypeX())
    blah
```

I've no idea how to do this in Protobuf-NET.

Sample .proto file:

```
package Messaging;

message Message {
    optional string uuid                = 1;

    optional Map map                = 2;
    optional Block block                = 3;
    optional Tile tile              = 4;
}

message Map {
    repeated Block block        = 1;
}

message Block {
    repeated Tile   tile            = 1;
    required int32 zCoord           = 2;
    required int32 version          = 3;
}

message Tile {
    required int32 xGCoord          = 1;
    required int32 yGCoord          = 2;
    required int32 zGCoord          = 3;
}
```

Using this to deserialize:

```
Messaging.Message msg = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Messaging.Message>(new MemoryStream(zmqMsg.Body));
```

Where to from here? How can I work out whether the message contains a Tile, Block or Map message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
if(msg.map != null) {
    // ...
}

if(msg.block != null) {
    // ...
}

if(msg.tile != null) {
    // ...
}
```

? Actually, if these options are mutually exclusive, this scenario could also be modelled in protobuf-net via inheritance (for the same layout) - however, since .proto has no syntax for that you would have to handle that manually.

Comment: I get an unexpected symbol error for the !. Can you explain the inheritance procedure to achieve the same layout? I spent many hours reading about this last night and couldn't work out how Protobuf-NET really works, as I'm new to C# (I come from C++).

Comment: @S.Richmond apologies; my 'phone must have eaten the `=`... fixed

Comment: Well that compiles thanks. The question is answered. Is this the right way to use protobuf-NET?

Comment: @S.Richmond it is a perfectly *valid* way of using protobuf-net, especially if you are starting from a pre-existing .proto definition; protobuf-net does not *require* you to use such, though - you can also start from code-first, i.e. just have your DTO classes and no .proto in sight.